# sharepoint 2013 provider hosted app using client identity has issues with access token

Tags: sharepoint-2013, access-token, siteminder

My provider hosted app is trying to send the client identity in addition to the app identity. I had to modify TokenHelper, SharePointContextProvider , SharePointContext to make it work with our claims provider siteminder. I was able to make the app only work but I get the following error while trying to send the client identity.

```
EncodeProviderUserKey couldn't encode provider user key for input [originalIssuerType:'Unknown'] [originalIssuerIdentifier:'office:idp:forms:siteminder claims issuer'] [providerUserKeyValue:'identifying claim value masked']
```

I tried creating the following claims

```
 new JsonWebTokenClaim(NameIdentifierClaimType, identity.UserId),
 new JsonWebTokenClaim("nii", "urn:office:idp:trusted:siteminder claims issuer")
```

Do I need to pass something that identifies the issuer type?
Is the format in which I am passing nii correct? "siteminder claims issuer" is the name of the claims provider in sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.

First upgrade to August 2014 CU or higher

Second make sure your claims provider implements SupportsUserKey.

I wrote a blog post on my journey here http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2015/02/on-premises-claims-authenticated-sharepoint-2013-and-hybrid-apps-hosted-in-azure/